# How to protect React component from global styles?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react component that will be embedded into an old website. The problem is that this website has some global styles with tag selectors, e.g:

```css
p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Removing these styles from the website is not an option.
So is there any way I can prevent these styles from reaching my component apart from just overriding them?

Comment: i doubt if there is a better option than overriding them

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your .p inside your own class.
Example in plain HTML:

```
<div class = "you-wrapper">
   ...
   ...
   ...
   <p></p>
   ...
</div>
```

And in you react code, add your own css:

```
.you-wrapper p { font-size: 15px; color:red;}
```

**Edited:**

```
/* your css */ 
.your-wrapper * { all: unset; }
.you-wrapper p { font-size: 15px; color:red;}
```

Comment: Yep, that was what I thought about initially, but there's no way to control which exact global styles will be added to the website later (I dont have any control over website codebase)

Comment: Maybe: 
/* your css */
.your-wrapper * {  all: unset; }
.... you css code...

*answer edited

Answer (score 0):

Create a particular css file for this component and again assign the style for p in this page particularly. It will replace the global one.
OR
You can use inline css because it has more preference than the external css.